# Binding to a drop down list in MVC and sending back selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, view, model

I am having trouble getting the value of the selected item from a drop down list.

Apologies for how much code I've posted, but it is very simple code to read.

When I edit a vehicle my Get Edit method returns the vehicle and the dropdown list has the correct VehicleType selected in the view.

**BUT**

When my [HttpPost] Edit gets the model back, the the VehicleType is null, the other fields, name, description are correctly updated.

I have a class called Vehicle and one called VehicleType

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set;        
    public virtual VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleType
{
    public int VehicleTypeID { get; set; }
    public string VehicleTypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

in my controller I have an get and set edit methods

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Vehicle myVehicle = db.Vehicle.Find(id);
    if (myVehicle == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    PopulateVehicleTypeList(myVehicle.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID);
    return View(myVehicle);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Vehicle myVehicle)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(myVehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(myVehicle);
}
```

And my view 
        //View 
    @model Vehicle

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Vehicle</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VehicleID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehicleType.VehicleTypeDescription)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("VehicleTypeID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehicleType.VehicleTypeID)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you should do.
Firstly, create a view Model which has Vehicles and VehicleTypes

```
public class VehicleViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VehicleTypes { get; set; }
    public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, in your view , change to DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.Vehicle.VehicleType,
Model.VehicleTypes,
"-- Select a vehicle type --", null)
```

Your controller will look something like this:

```
 VehicleViewModel viewModel = new VehicleViewModel
 {
    Vehicle vehicle  = <populate via Linq query>
    VehicleTypes = VehicleTypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.VehicleTypeID,
        Text = VehicleTypeDescription 
    }).ToList(),

    vehicle = vehicle

 };
```

Hope that helps.